# How to sort a List<String> in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I have a string that I need to display in ascending order.

```
List<String> myList = [2. Grammar, 3. Pronunciation, 1. Verbs];
```

Is there any way to achieve this [1. Verbs, 2. Grammar, 3. Pronunciation]

Answer (score 0):

If its a list of string it has to be in quotes.

```
void main() {
  List<String> myList = ['2.Grammar', '3.Pronunciation', '1.Verbs'];
myList.sort();
  print(myList);
}
//[1.Verbs, 2.Grammar, 3.Pronunciation]
```

Comment: My List is from Shared Preferences and somehow I get the List in this format.

Comment: In console its printed without quotes. But its still strings. You can use list.sort() and print it. It should print the sorted list